# Get frames of the video and perform modifications in that frame in android

Tags: android, android-ndk, ffmpeg, android-videoview, android-mediacodec

I need to get the frames a video and do some modification on it like drawing something on it or write some text. Then on saving I need that video with that modifications.

Please suggest me the best way to do that. Any help is appreciated.

Please see the below app for to understand my problem

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.techsmith.apps.coachseye.free

Comment: So you want to decode a video, modify the frames, and re-encode the video?  For broad portability many people seem to like ffmpeg, for best performance (but only on API 18+) you can use MediaCodec, e.g. http://bigflake.com/mediacodec/#DecodeEditEncodeTest .

Answer (score 1):

You can try INDE Media Pack - https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/intel-inde-media-pack-for-android-tutorials

It has transcoding\remuxing functionality as MediaComposer class and several sample effects like Grayscale, TextOverlayEffect etc. For exampe effect to put text: https://github.com/INDExOS/media-for-mobile/blob/master/Android/samples/effects/src/com/intel/inde/mp/effects/TextOverlayEffect.java. It could be easily enhanced to other effects

[image]

[image]